# Get google places autocomplete value only if the input is selected

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I want to get data from my Google places auto-complete input only if the user is selected one of the drop-down options. I don't want inputs like 'shdkajdjjdoiacn'. How can I do this? The code I use is:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {};
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
$('button').click(function(){
console.log(autocomplete.description);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Autocomplete()` function raises an event when the user exits the input field. You could use that event to populate a set of hidden fields, with values that the Autocomplete provides. Those values will remain blank if no valid selection was made from the dropdown, and therefore you can base your program logic upon whether or not those fields contain data. Examples of values provided in different fields by Autocomplete: street, city, state, country, LatLng coordinates.

To do this, add code similar to the following, in your `initialize()` function:

```
function initialize() {
  /* existing lines of code */
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  /* When user selects an address from the dropdown, 
     populate the address fields in the form */
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                fillInAddress();
            });
}
```

Next, create your `fillInAddress()` function, which will look something like the following. Please see [this reference link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_results), to get complete details about how to use it.

```
function fillInAddress() {
    /* Get the place details from the Autocomplete object. */
    /* The Autocomplete.getPlace() call retrieves a PlaceResult object */

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    /* Use data from place.address_components[] according to your needs */
    /* For reference, use the link: */
    /* https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_results */
}
```